# Joomla 2.5 'Alternative Menu Items' and 'Category Blog' (Multiple template layout overrides for the same component)

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, blogs

I've come across a very strange problem relating to 'Alternative Menu Items', the usage is described here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6

The following files are located in: `templates/testtemplate/html/com_content/category` and these are the steps I took:

These files:
`blog.php, blog.xml, blog_children.php, blog_item.php, blog_links.php`

Have been changed to:
`bloggal.php, bloggal.xml, bloggal_children.php, bloggal_item.php, bloggal_links.php`

For file bloggal.xml – I changed this part:
`<layout title="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_TITLE"`

To:
`<layout title="Blog Gallery"`

Then added sub headings to bloggal.php and bloggal_item.php so I can see if the child items are in effect.

Now the interesting part is bloggal.php works fine but the child items drawn from bloggal_item.php do not come up.

I've done this test with the same template on multiple Joomla installs, on one of them it seems to work and the rest it does not.

The only thing I can think of is Joomla may have had a regression since the working one was an updated install and the rest are more recent versions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I should've posted this sooner. I figured out the issue, I renamed:

```
<field name="layout_type"
    type="hidden"
    default="blog"
/>
```

To:

```
<field name="layout_type"
    type="hidden"
    default="bloggal"
/>
```

Essentially looking for a model that doesn't exist.

If you did this, do the following to fix it:

1. Rename `default="whatever"` back to `default="blog"`
2. In your database go to `_menu` table
3. Look for your menu item via the title column
4. Head over to the params and change `{"layout_type":"bloggal"...` to `{"layout_type":"blog"...`

Answer (score 0):

Starting Joomla 1.6 you can choose an alternate layout for each category. Including those you have overrides for. No need to select an alternate layout when configuring menu items ;)